# Overloading [] in matrix class

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to overload the operator[] so i can directly access the matrix instead of using the array.

What have I done:

.h:

```
#include <array>
#include "vector.h"
 using namespace std;
struct Matrix2d{
 array<float,4> positions;

 //Constructors
 Matrix2d(float x11, float x12, float x21, float x22);

 float operator[](int index);
 ....
```

.c:

```
float Matrix2d::operator[](int index){
return this->positions[index];
}
Matrix2d operator+(Matrix2d& mat1, Matrix2d& mat2){
 Matrix2d aux(0, 0, 0, 0);
 aux[0] = mat1[0] + mat2[0];
 aux[1] = mat1[1] + mat2[1];
 aux[2] = mat1[2] + mat2[2];
 aux[3] = mat1[3] + mat2[3];
return aux;
```

}

What happens is that aux[i] gives an error "must be a modifiable lvalue" but if I do aux.positions[i] it works.

I have seen [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/subscripting_operator_overloading.htm) for reference and it works so I don't understand why my version isn't not working...

Comment: I'd expect a `Matrix2d::operator[]` to return a row or column, not a single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### References to the rescue

You will need to return a reference to the element within the container from `operator[]` in order to be able to modify this given element from the outside.

Currently you are returning a temporary copy of the desired element, which—as stated in your question—does not allow for such modification, it is however perfectly fine when just wanting to *read* values (since you do not care about copying in such case).

---

#### Proposed Resolution

The fix is as easy as appending an `&` to the return-type of said operator, but please mind that you should probably add a const-overload of the same function (so that you can access elements of a `Matrix2d` that is logically `const`.

```
struct Matrix2d {
  ...

  float& operator[](int index);

  // float const& operator[] (int index) const
  // ^- you probably also want this

  ...
};
```

```
float& Matrix2d::operator[](int index){
  return this->positions[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this:

```
 aux[0] = mat1[0] + mat2[0];
```

What you're trying to do here is, in that order:

1. get the `float` **value** of `aux` at position 0,
2. get the `float` *values* of `mat1` and `mat2`, each at position 0, and then
3. assign the sum to the float **value**.

Notice my emphasize of "value"– what you're trying to do is literally trying to convince the compiler e.g. that `7.0 = 3.0 + 10.0`; your compiler says "hey, I can't assign a value (13.0) to a constant expression (7.0)".

The solution to that is not returning the *value*, but a *reference* to the entry in the matrix. I recommend googling for "returning a reference".